# Intersections of a Set of Intervals

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given a finite collection $\mathcal{B}$ of closed intervals $[i,j]$ such that among any three intervals $B_1 \in \mathcal{B}, B_2 \in \mathcal{B}, $ and $B_3 \in \mathcal{B}$, $\exists$ some $k \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $k$ is in at least two of $B_1, B_2, B_3$, show that $\exists$ $c_1$ and $c_2$ such that $c_1 \in B_i$ or $c_2 \in B_i$ $\forall B_i \in \mathcal{B}$.

By the way, $\forall$ means for all, $\exists$ means there exists, and $\in$ means in.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For each $B\in\mathscr{B}$ let $B=[x_B,y_B]$. Let

$$c_1=\min_{B\in\mathscr{B}}y_B$$

and

$$c_2=\max_{B\in\mathscr{B}}x_B\;.$$

Fix $B_1,B_2\in\mathscr{B}$ such that $y_{B_1}=c_1$ and $x_{B_2}=c_2$.

Let $B\in\mathscr{B}$ be arbitrary; clearly $c_1\le y_B$ and $x_B\le c_2$. Suppose that $c_1\notin B$ and $c_2\notin B$; then $c_1<x_B$ and $y_B<c_2$, and the three intervals $B_1,B$, and $B_2$ are pairwise disjoint. This contradiction shows that $B\cap\{c_1,c_2\}\ne\varnothing$, as desired.